# WP check if the page is a child of a child

Tags: wordpress

I know, I can check if a page is a parent page or is a child page with

```
if($post->post_parent)
```

but, I need to check if a page is a child page of another child page like:

- parentpage

  - child of parenntpage

    - child of child of parentpage

I need to know if the page is "child of parentpage", or is "child of child of parentpage"

there is a solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: Get the details for the page id that you get in `$post->post_parent`, and check if that has a parent as well.

Comment: ok, but I do not know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wp_get_post_parent_id()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_parent_id) for this:

```
if ( $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID ) ) {
    // is a child
    if ( wp_get_post_parent_id( $parent_id ) ) {
         // is a child of a child
    } 
}
```

Instead of `$post->ID` you can use `get_the_ID()`